# Detecting Apache Log4j vulnerability presence in gradle transitive dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, log4j2

There is a recent vulnerability in log4j https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228 which has criticality score of 10

How to check the presence of Log4j vulnerable versions in gradle so that it would list all the dependencies including the transitive dependencies?

Comment: `./gradlew -q dependencies|grep -i log4j` - This should give you the version of log4j-dependencies (if any) that are used.

Comment: @Turing85, shouldn't that be an answer, rather than a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
./gradlew -q dependencies
```

To list the dependency tree. It will list all dependencies with their respective version. Since this output can be lengthy, we can filter it down with `grep`:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies | grep -i log4j
```

This will list all `log4j`-dependencies with their respective version.

Comment: There is dependencyInsight in gradle as well? any idea how that is different and should be used/ not used?

Comment: gradle -q dependencyInsight

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation on `dependencyInsight`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection). It states that: "*... Every Gradle project provides the task `dependencyInsight` to render the so-called dependency insight report from the command line. Given a dependency in the dependency graph you can identify the selection reason and track down the origin of the dependency selection. ...*"

Answer (score 1):

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency org.apache.logging.log4j 
 --configuration scm
```

There is another way to check this list using dependencyInsight as per the article:-
https://venturebeat.com/2021/12/17/how-to-detect-whether-you-have-the-log4j2-vulnerability/